# Machine Learning model to find items that are frequently bought together using Hadoop Spark

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, apache-spark, apache-hadoop

I need to do my master thesis under Big Data Analytics - Machine Learning subject. I was challenged to create a Market Basket Analysis project on retail industry.

My dataset contains transactions of a supermarket over a year and I will have to predict which products are associated.

The requirements for my project are:
- We must visualize the evolution of the model (Learnable Evolution Model)
- Must be done using Hadoop tool (+ Spark)

I already look for multiple source codes/tutoriais to learn how can I do this but I can't find a machine learning implementation project for find patterns using Spark...

Anyone have an idea how can I find some good tutorials to learn this skills for me to do my master thesis algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about learnable evolution models, but Spark ML has a module for [collaborative filtering](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-preview/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html). This can be used to find objects that are similar/often bought together etc. [Amazon uses it](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx6J5RM20WPG5V/Building-a-Recommendation-Engine-with-Spark-ML-on-Amazon-EMR-using-Zeppelin) to show you the "People who bought this also bought these items" feature on their website.